# Get subscribers UID of a user through Graph API

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

A few weeks ago Facebook allowed to subscribe a user. Can we access the UID of these subscribers for one user through the Graph API or FQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously the graph API path should be:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/_UID_/subscribers
```

the path is valid, not documented though.

hope this helps

Comment: You also need the `user_subscriptions` permission